# Changing iOS app localization run time

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

How can I change my iOS app localization runtime the same as Booking.com iOS app. The app doesn't need to be restarted after changing language.
Do I need to handle everything by code and not using iOS localization system?

How does it change layout from RTL to LTR and vise versa in run time?

Comment: You need do this in IOS 9 or superior?

Answer (score 1):

You can change app localization at a run time please check [this](https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4).

To change layout from Right to left and left to right you can use bellow line of code:

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```